# Eureka Mignon grinders and dosing cups?

Tags: espresso, grinder

Do the Eureka Mignon grinders (Silenzio, Specialita) work well with a dosing cup such as the Rhinowares?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a few details what you mean by “work well”? If we know your criteria, we can probably give you better answers. And as for all new users, the [tour] and the [help] are recommended to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they do, provided you remove the portafilter holder and don't put dosing cup too far away from the hole, it is only as wide as a portafilter after all so there could be some spilt grounds if it's not close enough.

I found a small wooden brick that fits in front of the Mignon and has the perfect height for my dosing cup. I just coloured it black and now it looks as if it's a part of the grinder.